# How do I electrocute myself?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

As per [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129487/why-am-i-tripping-out), I've already figured out I can drug myself.  But there's another Steam achievement that says to complete a procedure after *electrocuting* myself.

[image: Surgetricity]

Clearly this is something I have to try.

How can I achieve this? When I think about things in the environment that might electrocute me, nothing comes to mind, and the achievement icon doesn't seem very helpful either.

Comment: The defibrillator?

Comment: @Mana I haven't seen one of those.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Electrocuting yourself is simple! Just stick a scalpel (or anything small and metal, really) into this electrical outlet (within 10 seconds of starting if you want the achievement)!

[image]

It will reverse your movement, making surgery incredibly difficult. Left becomes right, forward becomes backward, and the awkward controls become... awkwarder.

It's worth mentioning that there is also an achievement for being both drugged and electrocuted at the same time, as well as a subsequent achievement for completing the surgery in that fashion (within 20 seconds of starting).

Comment: I hope *no surgeon* in the world will try to perform such a surgery after playing this game, lol.

Comment: I just noticed that [this can also be done in the Ambulance levels](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dgqpS.jpg).  Not sure about the space ones.