# Why has my screen turned weird in Surgeon Simulator Mobile?

Tags: surgeon-simulator

My screen suddenly turned all weird and the place where I aim moves on its own. This isn't the first time it's happened but I don't know why it happens.

I'm playing on iPad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I tripping out?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129487)

Answer (score 1):

Does your screen look something like this?
[image]

If this is the case then you injected yourself with the green needle, normally used to stop blood loss. To get rid of the effect you can inject yourself with the blue needle, but don't inject the patient with it or it will make them bleed faster.

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out, I am on iPad and I touched the needle tip on accident. Thank you